# Designation for a function that BOTH manipulates objects AND returns a value, in contrast to functions that either does the former or the latter?

Tags: terminology

A long time ago, I found out that there were designation for this, but now I forgot it. If the title is misleading, please let me know.

For example, an IEnumerator in C# has a function, MoveNext(), that advances the enumerator to the next element of its collection, you could use it for moving to the next element and/or for checking if there is a next element, since it returns bool.

MoveNext() is not restricted to one use case, like voids that just do something inside their bodies, or functions that just returns a value.

Other methods that have this kind of unconstrained use:

- HashSet's Add, which returns a bool if the element already exists but can just be used to try to add the element.
- Stack's Pop, which returns the last object and also moves the structure.
- Queue's Dequeue, the same for Stack, but returning the first object.
- etc.

A little example of the multi-use of such methods:

```
public class Example
{
    Queue<int> testQueue;

    public Example()
    {
        testQueue = new Queue<int>();
        testQueue.Enqueue(1);
        testQueue.Enqueue(2);
        testQueue.Enqueue(3));
        testQueue.Enqueue(4);

        /// As function:
        int v = testQueue.Dequeue(); // I get 1.

        /// As method, just to take the elements out.
        testQueue.Dequeue();
        testQueue.Dequeue();
        // The first element is 4.
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help, and excuse me again if the title is somehow ambiguous.

Comment: Not clear what you’re asking. Your question is about a function, your example code is a constructor that clearly doesn’t apply.

Comment: His example fits perfectly.  It shows how Dequeue manipulates the queue AND has a return value.  His Example constructor is also an example of the behavior he is questioning the name of; It both creates and object and does this queue creation and manipulation. 
To be fair, Dequeue's removal and return of the first element are not completely decoupled.  It is returning the object that was pulled out of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

If a function does something else beside returning a value, then it is a function with a [side effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). A function without side effects is a [pure function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: This is not completely correct; a function can do many things before returning a value and still be called pure. The keyword is not "**does** something [beside returning]", the keyword is "**changes** something"

Answer (score 0):

If a function manipulates any kind of data structure, or object, it is a function with a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). A function with side effects does not guarantee that the returned value always will be the same for identical state and for identical parameters, if there is any parameters.

A function *without* side effects is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). A pure function, in a given state and a given parameter will always return the same value.

To answer your question in full:

- A **non-void function that changes something** is a *function with side effects*.
- A **non-void function that only returns something** is a *pure function*.

That leaves us with the function that "does something but doesn't return anything". By the definitions above, such a function would also be a function with side-effects, even if it doesn't return any kind of value.